# how to read characters one by one in textbox in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, string, iteration, substring, character

I want to read the value given by user in text box in vb.net.
if they give value ABC , i want to read the string one by one and display the particular character(ex. 3rd character(c)) in another text box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have 2 text boxes and a button:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim textBox1InputString As String
    textBox1InputString = TextBox1.Text

    ' Call ToCharArray function.
    Dim array() As Char = textBox1InputString.ToCharArray

    ' If we input ABC and we want C
    TextBox2.Text = array(2)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

```
For i = 0 To TextBox1.Text.Length
    If i = 2 Then
        TextBox2.Text = TextBox1.Text(i)
    End If

Next
```